# Убунту терминал и длинные виндовс-имена

Tags: linux, bash

Не знаю, чья была идея, но есть Убунту-сервер с удалёнкой, на который подмонтирован NTFS-диск с длинными русскоязычными именами ("Разработка проэктной документации для проекта "$projectname"", "Личная папка сотрудника "$bastardname"" и так далее). Внутри по десять подпапок с такой же длины именами.

Вопрос. Мне из терминала надо по этим папкам ходить, а я баш вижу второй раз в жизни. И `cd /data/storage/flies/Документы для отсылки в директорат` посылает меня по неустановленному адресу (нет такой папки, говорит)

ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Аргументы команд разделяются пробелами, вот пробелы в пути и режут его, получается несуществующий путь `data/storage/flies/Документы`. Заворачивайте аргументы в какие-нибудь кавычки: `cd "/data/storage/flies/Документы для отсылки в директорат"` или экранируйте пробел: `/data/storage/flies/Документы\ для\ отсылки\ в\ директорат` (автодополнение с помощью Tab автоматически экранирует)

Comment: Спасибо, заработало )

Comment: Удобно ходить по папкам в `midnight commander`-е. Аналог norten commander для dos или  far manager для windows. Если установлен, то вызывается командой `mc`. Есть ещё какая-то упрощенная версия, но не помню как называется.

Comment: nort*o*n commander. Еще есть vifm, но это более серьезный инструмент, не все осилят

Answer (score 3):

Заключите имена папок с пробелами в кавычки, двойные или одинарные:

```
~$ mkdir -p './data/storage/flies/Документы для отсылки в директорат'
~$ cd './data/storage/flies/Документы для отсылки в директорат'
~/data/storage/flies/Документы для отсылки в директорат$
```